# Is there a way to surpress all command line output, including errors, from Powershell

Tags: powershell, command, output, line

When calling Powershell from a Python script (`subprocess.Popen`), I am looping through a list of AD Domain Controllers. For each controller that fails to recognize the AD object, I want to suppress the errant output.

Using `| Out-Null` at the end of the Powershell command has no effect.

Python script:

```
for server in ADDomainList:
    cmd = 'powershell.exe get-ADComputer ' + hname + ' -Server ' + server + ' | Out-Null'
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```

From Powershell command line:

```
get-ADComputer computer-name -Server server.domain.com
```

Unwanted Output:

```
Get-ADComputer : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '?'.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-ADComputer computer-name -Server server.domain.com ?
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

Result of 0 or 1 returncode is all that I need to capture for next execution steps. I don't want any output to the console.

Comment: add input validation code to your python code OR to your PoSh script.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all streams to null like so `*> $null`. This will result in no output.

```
cmd = 'powershell.exe get-ADComputer ' + hname + ' -Server ' + server + ' *> $null'
```

If you wanted to pipe to `Out-Null` or to any other cmdlet, you can also redirect all output to the success stream, and pipe to another cmdlet like so:

```
cmd = 'powershell.exe get-ADComputer ' + hname + ' -Server ' + server + ' *>&1 | Out-Null'
```

[Here is some more information about redirection in Powershell.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that takes advantage of the PowerShell 
"try and catch" feature. By using this in a loop, the errant 
responses are eliminated.

I find the server I need with PowerShell try and catch

```
cmd = 'powershell.exe try{get-ADComputer ' + hname + ' -Server 
' + server + ' | Out-Null}catch{}'
```

Once I have the correct server, I use '| Out-Null' to get rid of 
the default PowerShell output.

```
subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe get-ADComputer ' + hname + ' 
-Server ' + sname + ' -Properties '
'OperatingSystem,PasswordLastSet | Export-CSV adcomputer.csv - 
Delimiter "*" -NoTypeInformation | Out-Null')
```